# RESTful API test, cookie is not carried along to the next request

Tags: node.js, http, http-headers, request

I need all the cookies to be carried along to the next request when I making http request to localhost when testing RESTful API. 
nodejs default http module doesn't support cookie, but I heard [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) support cookie by setting the 'jar: true' in options.

> Cookies are disabled by default (else, they would be used in
>   subsequent requests). To enable cookies, set jar to true (either in
>   defaults or options) and install tough-cookie.

first, what do they mean by 'install tough-cookie'? I trid 'npm install tough-cookie --save' to my project and then

```
tough = require('tough-cookie')
```

in testing code but it doesn't work. Do i have to assign tough to some setup options? Here is my code to make http request to localhost:

```
var get = function(path, paramObj, cb) {
    return Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        var options = {
            url: 'http://' + hostname + ':' + port + path,
            method: 'GET',
            qs: paramObj,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'User-Agent': 'request',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'            

            },
            jar: true // even I set true, cookie doesn't carry along to next request
        };
        request(options, function(err, response, body) {
            if (!err && response.statusCode === 200) {
                try {
                    var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
                    cb(parsed);
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log('get() - Parsing JSON error');
                    cb(body);
                }
            }
        });
    });
};



var post = function(path, paramObj, cb) {
    var options = {
        url: 'http://' + hostname + ':' + port + path,
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(paramObj),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'User-Agent': 'request',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'            
        },
        jar: true  // doesn't work
    };
    request(options, function(err, response, body) {
        if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
            // console.log('response is:');
            console.log(response.headers);
            try {
                var parsed = JSON.parse(body);
                console.log('parse json good');
                cb(parsed);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log('post() - Parsing JSON error');
                cb(body);
            }
        }
    });

};
```

again, my purpose is

> All the cookies to be carried along to the next request, as it is in browser.

What shall I do? Can you edit on top of my code? Thank you!